# Using Javascript to submit a form

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS on a registration page which should have no effect on this.

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" method="POST" action="registerProcess.php">
```

I have that form and the javascript

```
document.registerform.submit()
```

will not submit the form.... any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the Javascript code is being called? Insert an "alert" or other debug line in there to make sure the code is running. It looks like what you have should work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is usually caused by having a form control (usually a submit button) with a name or id of 'submit'. This clobbers the submit method; rename it.

Comment: Maaan I was so lost, I don't think I ever stared at three lines of js code for such a long time. This was it. Renamed the submit button and everything works like magic. Thank you very much indeed for sharing this mighty piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
document.getElementById('registerform').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
 `document.forms.items(0).submit();`